# How can I set the HTTP headers in a Watir webdriver session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-headers, watir, watir-webdriver

I am using Watir in RoR to request pages from my website. I would like to set the HTTP headers for a request - how can that be done?

Comment: That cannot be done by using Watir, because Watir is meant to mimic real user. What do you need to accomplish exactly?

Comment: I realize this is something I can do using https://github.com/alisterscott/webdriver-user-agent - this is so that I can mimick a specific browser.

Comment: This only allows you to change user-agent and not the http headers in general. If you needed to change user-agent in the first place then this library can help you indeed :)

Comment: I can get away with only setting the user agent, so I will accept the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize this is something I can do using [github.com/alisterscott/webdriver-user-agent](https://github.com/alisterscott/webdriver-user-agent).